# How to add TrimBox and BleedBox without fonts being rasterized

Tags: pdf-generation, ghostscript

I want Ghostscript to prepare PDFs for print production. The input PDF (Version 1.3) is in RGB, uses transparency and has crop marks.

1. Convert colors to CMYK by applying an ICC profile
2. Add a TrimBox and a BleedBox

I managed to achieve the steps above using the following command:

```
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFX  -r100 -dOverrideICC=true -sOutputICCProfile=ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -dRenderIntent=3 input.pdf -c "[ /PAGES pdfmark << /PDFXSetBleedBoxToMediaBox false /PDFXTrimBoxToMediaBoxOffset [29 29 29 29] /PDFXBleedBoxToTrimBoxOffset [8 8 8 8] >> setdistillerparams" -f
```

But unfortunately the fonts are getting rasterized.
I found out that `-dPDFX` causes that. 
But it seems like `-dPDFX` is needed to add the TrimBox and BleedBox. Without `-dPDFX` the fonts remain unchanged but the boxes won't be added.

I'm on OSX, the PDF contains two *Type 3* fonts.
Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Put everything useful to answer your question helpfully *in the question itself*. Do not hide pivotal information like `I use transparency in my [1.3] PDFs` somewhere in comments: this is not chat.

Comment: @greybeard thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, a few points:

Ghostscript (and more particularly the pdfwrite device) doesn't **add** anything to PDF files. It makes brand new PDF files from the supplied input, which may or may not be a PDF file.

The process is described [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/VectorDevices.htm#Overview) and I'd suggest you read it. Essentially you cannot assume that the content of the produced PDF file bears any relationship at all to the content of the input, if it's a PDF file.

Your usage of ICC profiles is not causing the conversion to CMYK, that's done by setting ColorConversionStrategy. Your setting of OverrideICC and OutputICCProfile aren't doing anything and you should remove those switches. In addition you should not set ProcessColorModel if you are setting ColorConversionStrategy. Similarly setting RenderIntent does nothing at all with the pdfwrite device, drop that too.

Don't set the resolution. All that does is set the resolution of any content which must be rendered (eg creating a PDF file < version 1.4 from an input file containing transparency). So drop the -r100.

-dPDFX doesn't cause fonts to be rasterised.

If that's happening then it's almost certainly nothing to do with selecting PDFX, without seeing your input file I can't comment further.

-dPDFX is not necessary to create a PDF file with TrimBox or BleedBox.

Of course, what your PostScript **actually** does is create PDFX Bleed and Trim **Offsets**, and yes, if you want those then you need to set PDFX, clearly. On the other hand, if you actually want to set normal regular Bleed or Trim boxes then that is also documented in the pdfmark reference (see page 37 of the 1.7 pdfmark reference):

> The syntax for specifying a non-default page cropping for a particular
> page in a document is as follows:
> [ /CropBox [xll yll xur yur]
> /PAGE pdfmark The syntax for specifying the default page cropping for a document is as follows:
> [ /CropBox [xll yll xur yur]
> /PAGES pdfmark

Obviously you would Substitute Bleed or Trim for CropBox.

### Update

This command line:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=new.pdf  /temp/input.pdf -c "[/CropBox [100 100 7568 3784] /PAGES pdfmark" -f
```

for me produces a PDF file (new.pdf) which has a CropBox in the Pages tree root node. Entries in the Pages tree are inherited by all pages below the node where they are defined and when I open the file with Acrobatm I can see that the crop marks are no longer visible.

So for me, it all works fine, and without using PDFX. Adding -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK should be enough to get a CMYK file out. And since it isn't using PDF/X, it will maintain the transparency instead of rendering it. Note that since your file is all in DeviceGray, the colour is retained unchanged anyway.

I forgot to say that using /TrimBox instead of /CropBox works perfectly well for me as well, in exactly the same manner.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed advices. I just realized that my PDFs have version 1.3. Therefore I must set the resolution (-r100) as long as the fonts get rasterized.

Comment: If your input PDF file has transparency (even if it has no effect) and you set the CompatibilityLevel to 1.3 then the **entire** PDF file will be rendered to an image, not just the fonts. You probably don't want to do that, especilaly at 100 dpi because the output will look terrible. You could try using -dNOTRANSPARENCY instead (or as well). If the actual transparency operations have no effect then the resulting PDF 1.3 file will not be a rendered image. Of course if the original transparency did have some effect, tehn ignoring it will lead to an incorrect output PDF file.

Comment: You're right. I use transparency in my PDFs and can't ignore it. Is there a way to up the CompatibilityLevel? -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 seems to have no effect when using -dPDFX.
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFX -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -r10 -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK input.pdf -c "[ /PAGES pdfmark << /PDFXSetBleedBoxToMediaBox false /PDFXTrimBoxToMediaBoxOffset [29 29 29 29] /PDFXBleedBoxToTrimBoxOffset [8 8 8 8] >> setdistillerparams" -f

Comment: The Compatibility Level is set appropriately for the output. Why are you using PDF/X ? That in itself sets limits on the output level, it limits it to PDF 1.3, so you **can't** have any transparency in the output file, its not permitted by PDF/X-3 (which is the only version supported by pdfwrite).

Comment: I sticked to PDF/X as I couldn't manage to add a regular TrimBox. The Syntax for the CropBox works fine, but there's no TrimBox added with the following code:
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -c "[/TrimBox [10 10 300 300] /PAGES pdfmark" -f input.pdf

Comment: And how have you checked that there is no TrimBox ? AFAIK the TrimBox pdfmark works, without needing PDF/X (and note that your code doesn't add a TrimBox, it adds PDF/X-specific offsets which are obviously not going to work with anything except a PDF/X file. Since you need transparency, you shouldn't be using PDF/X. I cannot say why this doesn't work for you without seeing your input PDF file and trying it myself

Comment: I checked it using Preflight inside Acrobat. Would be great if you could give it a try using my test input file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/26d691e3bdf1ac6d9352ae215dec6bfd20200428150446/726b35
code: gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -c "[/TrimBox [10 10 300 300] /PAGES pdfmark" -f input.pdf

Comment: I've no idea why it's no working for me. Cropping works perfectly fine:

Comment: I know how to check the TrimBox in Acrobat. How do you check it within Acrobat?
Acrobat screenshots showing the missing TrimBox: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/57f6d505644881ecda4fb239df4fa17820200428170904/9499ee

Comment: I don't check it with Acrobat, I open the PDF file in an editor and read what's in there.

Comment: Appears to be an Acrobat bug. If I run the file produced by Ghostscript back through pdfwite a second time (which I don't reccomend) then the TrimBox gets placed in the Page dictionary ionstead of the Pages tree. Then Acrobat will properly display the TrimBox. With some effort you could write a PostScript program to process each page individually from the PDF file, and send a /PAGE pdfmark to set that specific page's TrimBox before processing the page. I believe that would put the TrimBox into each page rather than the tree.

Comment: I can confirm that if i open the PDF in an editor, I see the added TrimBox as well. Unfortunately I'm probably not able to write the PostScript program, as I've zero experience. If I can't do it,  I'll go for the awesome reprocessing "hack".

Comment: Let me know if you want to include the „hack“ in your answer. Otherwise I‘ll accept the current one. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'd prefer not to make the hackery too public, people have a habit of grabbing the first thing they see and using it as a solution without understanding the whole problem. I don't reccomend running through Ghostscript mulitple times because every pass runs the risk of degrading the quality. More trips means more chance of something going wrong. Of course eventually you reach the 'lowest common denominator' and nothing worse can happen, but still, best to avoid it if possible.